# MySQL syntax error when updating

Tags: php, mysql, implode

Can not find a problem in this script:

```
$delhash  = array();
$resultxx = mysqli_query($datba1,"SELECT htag 
FROM wall_hashtags 
WHERE publicat='$permid'") or die('Error1');

while(list($dht) = mysqli_fetch_row($resultxx)) {
$delhash[] = $dht;
}
```

The following update does not work:

```
$result_update = mysqli_query($datba1,"UPDATE wall_hashtags  SET
numbr=numbr-1 WHERE htag IN (".implode(",", $delhash).")")
die(mysqli_error($datba1));
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'first,second,third' at line 1

Array:

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($delhash); echo '</pre>';

Array
(
    [0] => first
    [1] => second
    [2] => third
)
```

Comment: use prepared Statement. to ba save agains SQL injection

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please make sure that you are updating using `IN()` clause with `varchar` values. Check [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) for more details.

So you should wrap it with `'`.

```
$result_update = mysqli_query($datba1,"UPDATE wall_hashtags  SET 
                 numbr=numbr-1 WHERE htag IN ('".implode("','", $delhash)."')")
                or die(mysqli_error($datba1));
```

Comment: This should be correct answer. Don't forget to wrap the string with quotes.

Comment: The `die` is in the `mysqli_query` too; also needs an `or`...or I'm not familiar enough with `mysqli` and this is valid?

Comment: @chris85 I guess `die()` is fine. Just required to add `or`.